# C++ Start multiple programs to scan computer for malware

Tags: python, c++, windows, batch-file, automation

I wonder if it's possible to create a c/c++ program to download  other programs like ninite.com but all virus/malware/spyware removal related.

At my job we use several good software like ccleaner, adwcleaner etc etc to clean computers.
I would like to have only ONE exe to download/run them all one after the other.

It would be a lot more better if we dont see them running, AKA running them in background

So is it possible, probably... but any one knows how to achieve that challenge? :)

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. However, you'll probably being violating some license clause in at least piece of software you download by doing this, so be careful if you plan to distribute it.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but I would prefer a simpler language for this task instead of C++. Look into writing a python script, or even a batch file.. Reduces the development effort a lot.

Comment: OMGtechy: I will not distribute it, its just i clean every employees computers, it will be to ease my task

lethal-guitar: Python or batch file can run program in background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of different options exist for this sort of work - here are a few that come to mind:

1. Windows Remote Management

   If you need to run your background download on many systems, I would suggest taking a look at WinRM:

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384426(v=vs.85).aspx
2. PowerShell

   Alternatively, if you already have a way to distribute and run a program on your target machines, and they're all capable of running PowerShell scripts, I suggest taking a look at writing a PS script to perform your download tasks. You most likely won't need any additional dependencies with this approach; your downloader could be a single solitary PS script.
3. Python

   As someone already mentioned in a comment, Python would be a nice choice if you're fine with distributing a Python interpreter to your target machines.

   By using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html) you should be able to bundle the Python interpreter along with your script, to avoid installing Python system-wide on your target machines. The following blog post has some useful tips on installing Python and virtualenv on Windows, which would be useful first steps toward building a distributable script bundle:

   http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/

Comment: The kind of answer i wanted! Accepted! big thanks